# What's the difference between stroganoff and goulash?

Tags: hungarian-cuisine, russian-cuisine

I know there are variants of stroganoff and goulash that are quite similar - to a point I could not tell one apart from the other. What are the defining properties of each that set them apart as different dishes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditional goulash is a stew/soup, usually using a cheaper cut of meat suited to slow cooking. It usually contains potatoes and other vegetables, as well as noodles.

A true stroganoff consists of paprika-dusted fillet steak quickly pan fried with mushrooms and onions in a sour cream and brandy sauce. It is usually served with rice.

I understand that in the US stroganoff can also refer to a stew made with similar ingredients as the traditional dish, and is served with noodles. This, coupled with the shared use of paprika, is evidently where the line blurs.

Comment: Note that a traditional gulyás does not actually contain any noodles, unless you count *chipetke* as noodles.

Comment: Yeah, as Marti says, if there's noodles, it's not gulyás. As for the difference between the two dishes, there's a pretty simple and absolute rule: stroganoff must contain mushrooms. Gulyás must not.